# Evaluate an integral in polar form

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

This problem is driving me crazy :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}{dx.dy}$$

Someone please solve this problem in details by sketching the required boundary and how did he calculate it. The final answer is $\pi/4$ Thanks in advance

Edit :  I am still learning polar coordinates , so i have failed to convert this double integral boundary to polar form !

Comment: What have you done so far to try and solve it. Show some working, people don't appreciate "please do this"

Comment: @HenryLee I have tried to solve it but i have failed to convert the boundaries to polar form . This is because i am not yet good in polar coordinates !

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @JohnDouma No its pi/4 , please solve it.

Comment: Yes. I see that. Look at Key Flex's answer. You have a unit circle centered at $(0,1)$. You are being asked to find the area of the bottom right quarter of it.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes i know , but i can't figure out the right limits for the double integration

Comment: Did you use the substitutions that Key suggested? I have no reason to doubt your sincerity but it does appear that you are unwilling to try to do this. Maybe you tried Key's substitutions and got nowhere. If you are unwilling to publish your attempt, why should someone be willing to publish a solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85347/discussion-between-john-adams-and-john-douma).

Comment: @JohnDouma  Ok bro , here is my attempt . My limits are as follows theta from 0 to Pi/2 and r from 0 to 2sin(theta) and the integrand will be rdrd(theta). The answer of this double integration will give me the area of right half of the circle , then multiplying this result by 1/2 will give me the answer . So this attempt is correct ? My answer was pi/4 , but i don't know if its luck or it is the right approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use the fact that $$x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\\r^2=x^2+y^2$$

You have $\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}dxdy$

From above we can say that $y=0,y=1$ and $x=0$, $x=\sqrt{2y-y^2}\implies x^2+(y-1)^2=1$, so it is a circle of radius $1$

Now can you continue from here?

Comment: Can you please help me in deriving the boundaries only ?

Comment: Are the limits will be : for r 0-->1 and for theta 0--> pi/4 ?

Comment: Here is my attempt . My limits are as follows theta from 0 to Pi/2 and r from 0 to 2sin(theta) and the integrand will be rdrd(theta). The answer of this double integration will give me the area of right half of the circle , then multiplying this result by 1/2 will give me the answer . So this attempt is correct ? My answer was pi/4 , but i don't know if its luck or it is the right approach ?

Comment: @Johnadams Yes, your approach and the answer are correct.

Answer (score 0):

note:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-(1-y)^2}}dxdy$$
so if $$x=\sqrt{1-(1-y)^2}$$
$$x^2=1-(1-y)^2$$
$$x^2+(y-1)^2=1$$
so it is a circle with centre $(0,1)$ and a radius of $1$
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 rdrd\theta=\pi$$

Comment: please check your limits for polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
$\int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}} dx dy = \int_0^1 x|_{0}^{\sqrt{2y-y^2}} =\int_0^1 \sqrt{2y-y^2} dy =  \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-(y-1)^2} dy$

Now Substitute $u:=y-1$, which leads you to $\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{1-u^2} du$

This is a standard integral, which is computed multiple times here in the forum (and on the whole internet), so we get:
$\int_{-1}^{0}\sqrt{1-u^2} du = \frac{1}{2}(u \sqrt{1-u^2} + arcsin(u))|_{-1}^{0}= \frac{1}{2}arcsin(-1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: please solve it using polar coordinates.